# Full screen apps get all muddled in VMware player

Tags: vmware-player

I'm running windows 7 that's running VMWare Player that is running Ubuntu 13.10.

Now everything is working perfectly apart from the full screen apps. In Ubuntu, I make apps full screen, and that's all great, but if I need to hop into windows for a second, I minimize VMWare player, and when I maximize it again, in Ubuntu all of my windows have jumped into different places.

It's really, really annoying. Any ideas how to stop this? It's wasting me so much time.